# Transfering data to a Flask App with AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, flask, google-chrome-extension

I want to transfer URLs from extension to a Flask app. Extension can access the current URL of the website. I am sending an AJAX request to Flask (connection is successful). But when I try to send the URL to Flask, the "test" page outputs a "None" value.

Users of this extension will enter a website. I want the extension to send this website's URL to Flask.
What is the right format to return the current URL to FLASK when this extension is being used? I want the test page to output the user's current URL.**

**main.py:**
In this part, the Flask has the function testfn() in which I try to get the request.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def testfn():
    data = request.get_json()
    return render_template("index2.html", **locals())


@app.after_request
def add_headers(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
    return response
```

**index2.html:**  In this part, I print the value of data, however in the page, I see a "None" value. I want to display URL instead of this "None" value.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>{{data}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js:**  In this part, I get the current URL of the website successfuly and send AJAX request.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
    var link = "";
    link = tabs[0].url;
    link = JSON.stringify(link);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/test/",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: link,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });   
});
```

Comment: check what data are you getting in `request.get_json()`

Answer (score 0):

To be sure set the `cache` to `False`.

[image]